# Показать элемент внутри скрытого элемента

Tags: javascript, css

Как отобразить указанные дочерние элементы внутри скрытого div'а

Есть код в котором .user_comment_body {display:none;} . Как показать .jcm-dropdown-menu вместе со всеми li ? Использование display: none; необязательно. Приветствуются любые способы которые позволят отображать только указанный элемент .

```html
<div class="user_comment_body">

  <div id="comment"></div>
  <div id="jlexcomment" style="" class="jcm-xsmall">
    <div id="jcm-header" style="display: block !important;">

      <ul class="jcm-top jcm-inline">
        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>

        <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>

        <li class="jcm-pull-right" style="position:relative;z-index:20">
          <div class="jcm-dropdown onRight">
            <a class="jcm-dropdown-toggle">Menu</a>
            <ul class="jcm-dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="_dx" id="jcm-notifications">Уведомления <span class="jcm-count-nof"></span></a></li>
              <li><a class="_dx" href="/signup/profile">Настройка</a></li>
              <li><a class="_dx" id="jcm-thumb-edit">Редактирование миниатюры</a></li>
              <li><a class="_dx jcm-user-cm" data-id="644">Комментарии</a></li>
              <li><a class="_dx" id="jcm-u-logout">Выход</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Subscribe/Sort by -->
      <ul class="jcm-top-secondary jcm-inline">
        <li>
          <a class="jcm-subscribe "><i class="jcm-icon-envelope"></i>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ни как............

Comment: Не представляется возможным, значения дочерних элементов зависят от значения родительских... Может если-бы вы более подробно описали что вы хотите сделать были-бы какие-то другие варианты обхода)

Comment: Спасибо. Но не обязательно использовать display: none; . Приветствуются любые способы которые позволят отображать только указанный <ul class="jcm-dropdown-menu">. Добавил эту корректировку к описанию вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

не думаю, что у вас получится. на то он скрытый.
Можете попробовать вариант

```
.user_comment_body {
    display: block;
}
.user_comment_body  > * {
    display: none;
}

.user_comment_body  > .нужный_блок {
    display: block;
}
```

Т.е. принцип такой, скрываете всё, кроме той ветви которая вам нужна, ну и так дальше по вложенности. используйте not

```
.user_comment_body {
    display: block;
}
.user_comment_body  > *:not(.нужный_блок) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Никак: если скрыть элемент, то все дочерние его элементы и псевдоэлементы тоже будут скрыты... вместо этого - ты можешь сплюснуть с помощью `width` или `height` или тем и тем `.user_comment_body` и задать ему `overflow: visible;` тогда дочерние элементы будут видны и ты спокойно сможешь их позиционировать

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  visiblity:hidden
}
#element_in_body {
  visiblity:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то я для этого находил html код нужного невидимого элемента, вырезал и вставлял в новый видимый элемент. Все это с помощью JavaScript.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).